# How to set the state of a tkinter Scale widget to disabled?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, tkinter-scale

I have been looking around for a way to disable the `Scale` widget of tkinter but I couldn't find one.

I tried a few things but none seem to work:

```
w = Scale(master, from_=0, to=100)
w.pack()
w.state(statespec=DISABLED)
w.config(state=DISABLED)
w.config(state='disabled')
w.configure(state='disabled')
```

Does anyone know if it possible or if there is a workaround ? I managed to get it to work fine for `Button` and `Checkbutton` widgets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
w.config(state=DISABLED,takefocus=0)
```

will make scale widget disabled.It nolonger move

```
from Tkinter import *

master=Tk()
w = Scale(master, from_=1, to=10)
w.config(state=DISABLED,takefocus=0)
w.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

Its works perfect for me.

Comment: Why are you imporint tkinter twice?

Comment: @BryanOakley No need for it.I Edited